# Is it advisable to run non-Knative deployment/services on Knative installed cluster?

Tags: knative, knative-serving, knative-eventing

Is it advisable to run non-Knative deployment/services on Knative installed cluster?
Or is it best to use a separate K8 cluster for k8 native containers?

Answer (score 0):

It should be fine to mix Knative and non-Knative workloads in the same cluster. Knative runs k8s-native containers; if you look at the underlying components of Knative Serving, you'll see Deployments and Pods just like other Kubernetes applications. Knative Eventing can deliver events to Kubernetes Services as well as Knative Serving and Eventing, so you can deliver events to a StatefulSet if that makes sense

Knative should also be compatible with Kubernetes quotas and limits, so it's possible to limit the number of pods or cpu resources used by Knative in a particular namespace. It should also be possible to mix Knative and other Kubernetes constructs (including things like MySQL provisioned by an operator) in the same namespace; I do this for my blog, for example.